# Trying to keep socket.io connection same between pages. Is there a framework that would allow me to do this?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, single-page-application

I am creating an Express app that uses a Socket.io connection for real-time updates. I would like to keep the Socket.io connection even if the user switches pages. Seeing that it doesn't seem to be possible, I was wondering if there was some framework that allowed you to have one .html page and would generate the pages based on that template (Like how Angular does it). Does a framework like this exist for Express? I looked into Vue, but am not sure that it will work.

I am currently sending static html files to the user. Any help with this problem is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your parent HTML page makes the socket.io connection then you can send pages to an iframe and the iframe can retrieve the parent socket connection.

Comment: @WLGfx if I understand you correctly, you're suggesting to have an index.html file in my public folder that contains an iframe that contains files sent by the server. Since it's the iframe that's being reloaded, and not the actual page itself, the socket.io connection should remain the same. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes, the parents .js file makes the socket.io.client connection and you can call from the iframe to the parents function to gain access to the socket. I'll come up with an example for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't go into detail on the html and css files as that's not necessary. The main page, or parent page (index.html) just needs this javascript file to make the socket.io-client connection.

```
var io = io();

function get_socket() {
    console.log("Return socket connection to iframe page");
    return io;
}

// handles server telling client to change page url in iframe
io.on("page", (page) => {
    $("#iframepage").attr("src", page);
    console.log("Page change: " + page);
});
```

In the html file I include jQuery and the socket.io-client.

When the iframe loads up the javascript files they can call the parent page for the socket connection just as simple as:

```
var socket = parent.get_socket();
```

When the iframe is changed then all the .on commands are refreshed. This is great for a single page application and logging in as when the tab/browser or app is closed even the server can catch the disconnect event.

Comment: Thanks for this! This also led me to use Angular which has also helped with using templates.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this, but you might be able to make the WebSocket connection from a [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API), and then have open page(s) communicate with the worker.

At a cursory glance, it looks like browsers used to not support WebSockets in workers, but that was fixed a few years ago.  You can count on browsers eventually killing your worker (and thus socket connection) if there are no pages open, and it looks like some browsers might do this even if there are still pages open, so you might need to experiment to see if this method is reliable enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way you can access socket.io instance  in request.

create socket-io.js file first:

```
const socketio = require('socket.io');
module.exports.io = (server) => {
   const io = socketio(server);
   io.on('connection', async function (socket, next) {
   });

   return io;
};
```

and after that import it in app.js file:

```
const { createServer } = require('http');

const socketio = require('./services/socket_io').io;
const server = createServer(app);

const io = socketio(server);
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   // instance socketio to req object
   req.socket = io;
   next();
});
```

with this config you can use socket io instance in every requests.

```
req.socket.emit("my_event", event)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! I did what you suggested and am now getting the following error: ```TypeError: req.socket.destroy is not a function```. Do you know how to fix this? I can post my code if that would help.
The error is coming from ```\node_modules\finalhandler\index.js:128```

Comment: I managed to fix this error, but am not sure how to implement your suggestion. I have a socket.js file on the client side that creates a socket with ```io()``` which I can then use in my other scripts to emit messages. I would like to keep the socket the same since I am storing variables such as the username, and if the socket refreshes, the ```socket.username``` returns null. Is there another way to get around this problem?

Comment: @MilanFerus-Comelo take a look for full example