# Is there a way to switch html files without disconnecting the client?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

**Background**

---

I'm making a game and I have two html files. One to login the player and the other for the game. The login right now is just to setup the connection and to get the players in the same room. Not really trying to save a profile for the user as it is not needed. If they disconnect then they can't reconnect. The game as well as the info they send will be deleted on disconnect. They will get kicked back to the login page where they will need to make a room and generate a new code or join a room with a code.

**Problem**

---

When I log them in and load the next html page with the game it disconnects them and reconnects them. I'm not creating a profile for each player so I can't recognize them on reconnecting to the server and I delete the game on disconnect so the game is gone. Right now I'm trying to setup a system to profile and authenticate them. I was just wondering if there was a way to switch html files without disconnecting the client as it would save me from doing extra work.

Also, if I allow them to reconnect then I would have to keep the game info even when they disconnect. So I save the key to the session in their local storage. What if they leave and clear their local storage? Or modify the code and delete the key? The server would treat them like a new player and create a new session. The old game data would stay in the server taking up space right? How would I deal with that? should I use a timeout so it deletes it if they don't come back in time?

Here is a piece of the what I got right now if that makes it more clear.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="index.js" charset="utf-8" defer></script>

<!--
 page structure
-->

<!-- game.html -->
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="app.js" charset="utf-8" defer></script>

<!--
 page structure
-->
```

```
// socket.js
export const socket = io({
  autoConnect: false, // I tried setting both of this to true still disconnects
  reconnection: false
});

// index.js
import { socket } from './socket.js'; // tried only using one js file still disconnects

/*
 login code // I socket.connect() somewhere in here
*/

// app.js
import { socket } from './socket.js';

/*
 game code
*/
```

This is just driving me crazy and I've read so much on socket.io yet can't find a solution I like. I've come up with some ways around this, but I would prefer not to take those routes just yet.

Comment: *clear their local storage* is not the only possible reason, they can simply decide no-return, or change a browser.

Comment: to the first question yes, you can change any content as you want, you can simply overwrite whole `body`.

Comment: @apple apple so instead of have two html files I switch to, I should just have one and change the body instead so it looks and acts like I'm switching html files?

Comment: If you have a parent page which contains an iframe, then the parent page holds the socket.io connection. Each page can then be loaded into the iframe and retrieve the same socket.io connection from the parent page. Only when the parent page is refreshed or closed then the socket.io connection is lost. Look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65226589/2979092

Comment: I like this idea. I'm tired so I'm gonna go to sleep and try this tomorrow, but I just read over iframes and I think this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: So I read up on this. This would make my application a SPA (Single Page Application) correct? I see I can do this with a framework like Vue. Would it be a smart decision to learn Vue and incorporate it into my project?

Comment: Not being a web dev myself I found socket.io great for my use case as it handles rooms behind the scenes for you so you can host many games at once from the one server as you can emit messages to a single room. The only other alternative would be websockets but a lot more behind the scenes coding I found. You can have multiple pages, but once the player logs in and starts a game, then it becomes an SPA for that part. The server can store players progress for next time.

Comment: Also another way of looking at it is that you may have lots of web connections to the server viewing pages, but you only want socket connections for those who are playing the games which lessons the load on the server.